# calculate percentage in R

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage

I am a beginner in R and R is for me actually only the means to analyse my statistical data, so I am far from being a programmer. I need some help with Building percentages of my variables from an Excel sheet. I Need R.total with R.Max as 100% base. this is what I did:

```
DB <- read_excel("WechslerData.xlsx", sheet=1, col_names=TRUE, 
                 col_types=NULL, na="", skip=0)
```

I wanted to to use `prop.table` 
but this dose not work with me. than I tried to make data frame

```
R.total <- DB$R.total 
R.max <- DB$R.max 
DB.rus <- data.frame(R.total, R.max)
```

but `prop.table` still dose not work. Can somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you want, but for this mock data.

```
r.total <- runif(100,min=0, max=.6) # generate random variable
r.max <- runif(100,min=0.7, max=1)  # generate random variable
df <- data.frame(r.total, r.max) # create mock data frame
```

You could try

```
# create a new column which is the r.total percentage of r.max
df$percentage <- df$r.total / df$r.max
```

Hope it helps.